# Create a report of user's privileges

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a table where i store the privileges of the users to grant or denied access to the differents modules of the software.

```
idUser     idModule
  1           1
  1           2
  1           3
  2           4
```

The user "1" has access to modules 1, 2, 3 but no 4.
The user "2" has access to 4 only.

So, the idModule is FK from Module table, if a user has access it will have a row in this table otherwise it will be denied.

```
idModule           Module
   1          Can Create Users
   2          Can Edit Users
   3          Can Delete Users
   4          Can View Users
```

I'd like a query that output:

```
idUser  Module1    Module2    Module3    Module4
  1        1          1          1          0
  2        0          0          0          1
```

This way is easy to do a report.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: And what Database product are you using? Oracle, Mysql, Sql server?

Comment: @Ghost MS Sql Server 2008 R2. Thanks

Comment: @hsanders i use CASE WHEN, hope to see other way.

Comment: Only other way I can think of would be using a `PIVOT`, but that's not really simpler for just a few values, and adding isn't that much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a simple de-normalization query:

```
select idUser
     , max(case when idModule=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Module1
     , max(case when idModule=2 then 1 else 0 end) as Module2
     , max(case when idModule=3 then 1 else 0 end) as Module3
     , max(case when idModule=4 then 1 else 0 end) as Module4
from   your_table
group by 1
```

Comment: If i add some modules, i have to edit this query. Is there a way it can be with 1, 2, 3 or N modules ?

Comment: Given you have a table with all values of idModule, you could write a procedure or macro that generates a select statement similar to above.  Perhaps you should ask another question or modify this one (I don't know the protocol).

Comment: Thanks Bob, i'll use "case when".